Deriving the matrix describing the linear transformation of rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$
So to Start, I just rotated the $x-y$ plane by say $\theta$ , thus obtaining
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)&0\\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we rotate the $z$ axis by angle $\phi$. This, however, doesn't change the operations done to the $x$ and $y$ axis.
so this would be
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)&\text{something}_1\\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)&\text{something}_2\\
\cos(\phi)&\cos(\phi)&\sin(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$$
how do I figure out the somethings?

What do you mean by “rotate the $z$-axis by angle $\phi$”? Rotations are ‘really’ described in terms of planes, like in your first sentence. So my interpretation of this sentence is that you’re subsequently rotating in the $x$-$y$ plane by $\phi$ so you just get the first matrix with $\theta +\phi$ instead.

I mean I now "tilt" the entire system about the $z$ axis by an angle $\phi$. So I'm basically depressing it ?

again, it depends how you tilt. Rotations are defined within a plane. So you need to tell me a plane in which I have to perform the rotation. The $z$-axis and ____??? You need to tell me another line so that it and the $z$-axis make up a plane, and then we can rotate in that plane. Play around with a book and start rotating it. You’ll immediately see why I’m asking you to be more precise.

Ok, what I mean to say is I'm yawing and pitching the system, by $\theta$ and $\phi$ respectively, how would I find such a rotation matrix ( say roll is 0).

The yaw-pitch-roll formulae are given in detail here. If you want to do things in a different order (pitch roll yaw or whatever), then simply multiply matrices in that order.

… and now I understand what you wanted to ask; you wanted to do a pitch, so  what I was looking for you to say is that you are performing a rotation in the $z$-$x$ plane by an angle $\phi$ (counterclockwise from the positive $z$-axis). i.e the $x$-axis was the missing ingredient you had to specify.
